# Derivative of $ C_m = \frac{{|x|}e^{2x}}{\pi^{1/2}}\int_0^t \alpha ^{-\beta/2}e^{\frac{-x^2}{\alpha}-\alpha } \mathrm d\alpha $

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a expression like this

$$ C_m = \frac{{|x|}e^{2x}}{\pi^{1/2}}\int_0^t \alpha ^{-\beta/2}e^{\frac{-x^2}{\alpha}-\alpha }d\alpha $$

I need to compute the values of $\partial C_m /\partial x$. I couldn't solve that using wolfram.

If anyone could help me solve this problem, that would be great.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

For simplicity $\beta$ can be used as $\frac{1}{2}$ .

Comment: Upper bound is t in the integral.

Comment: Sasha: Suggestion accepted and I changed the variable to `$$\alpha $$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate it as a product:
$$\frac{\partial{C_m}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}}\left(\frac{{x}e^{2x}}{\pi^{1/2}}\int_0^t {\alpha}^{-\beta/2}e^{-x^2/{\alpha}-{\alpha}}d{\alpha}\right) \\
=\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}}\left(\frac{{x}e^{2x}}{\pi^{1/2}}\right)\int_0^t {\alpha}^{-\beta/2}e^{-x^2/{\alpha}-{\alpha}}d{\alpha}+ \frac{{x}e^{2x}}{\pi^{1/2}} \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}}\left(\int_0^t {\alpha}^{-\beta/2}e^{-x^2/{\alpha}-{\alpha}}d{\alpha} \right) \\
= \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}}\left(\frac{{x}e^{2x}}{\pi^{1/2}}\right)\int_0^t {\alpha}^{-\beta/2}e^{-x^2/{\alpha}-{\alpha}}d{\alpha}+ \frac{{x}e^{2x}}{\pi^{1/2}}\int_0^t \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}} \left({\alpha}^{-\beta/2}e^{-x^2/{\alpha}-{\alpha}}\right)d{\alpha}
$$
for $x>0$
and in a similar way for $x<0.$

Comment: Thank you so much M. Strochyk. I think this is what I needed. I was not sure whether I could put the derivative inside the integral or not.